# Figurative language

Tags: idioms-in-context

Would a native speaker of English understand what is meant by a "a second head" and "third hand"?

"My friend sometimes jokes and calls his computer his second head and third hand. They have become so important that he says they have become a second head and a third hand to our lives."

They can be used in Russian. Do you have a similar expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recognize "second head and third hand" as an established idiom in English, though I understand what it means from your example.

The closest English idiom I can think of: if somebody is helping you do something, you could call that person *an extra pair of hands* (or if they are helping you gather information, *another pair of eyes/ears* as appropriate). This is a kind of metonymy where the person is identified by body parts that are salient to the situation.

Comment: Thus, "Computers have become another pair of eyes" or "The computer has become another pair of eyes" but adding "to our lives" is wrong, isn't it?

Comment: I've never heard 'a second head', but the concept of 'needing a third hand' is familiar enough to me in English, for instance if you need both hands to hold something steady and then want to do something to it.

Comment: How would you use it in a sentence? Could you  tell me please  if adding "to our lives" is wrong?